# In VBA Query cannot be completed

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

I want to find the sum of records from different tables and insert the output in a new column, when I run the code it show me the error:

"The query cannot be completed. Either the size of the query result is
 larger than the maximum size of the database (2GB) or there is not enough
 temporary storage space on the disk to store the query result"

And it highlight the line

> ```
> STD.Open sql, cnn, adOpenStatic
> ```

My code is the following

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Public db As DAO.Database

Public Sub SMain()
    Set db = Access.Application.CurrentDb
    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection

   Get_Value

End Sub

Private Sub Get_Value()
    Dim sql As String
    Dim STD As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ODR As DAO.Recordset
    Set ODR = db.OpenRecordset("Total_tbl")

    Do Until ODR.EOF
    DoEvents
    sql = "SELECT SUM(MONT_VOL.tot_n* STD_tbl.factor_n)AS TOTAL_N FROM MONT_VOL " & _
    " INNER JOIN (STD_tbl INNER JOIN Total_tbl ON STD_tbl.AREA =Total_tbl.AREA_1" & _
    " AND STD_tbl.AID = Total_tbl.AID)" & _
    " ON MONT_VOL.BID = STD_tbl.BLOCK" & _
    " WHERE MONT_VOL.BDATE = Total_tbl.Adate" & _
    " GROUP BY MONT_VOL.BID"
    STD.Open sql, cnn, adOpenStatic

        If STD.RecordCount <> 0 Then
            ODR.Edit
            ODR!New_Col= STD!TOTAL_N
            ODR.Update
        End If

        STD.Close
        ODR.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

What mistake I did?
And am I calling the output correctly on

> ODR!New_Col= STD!TOTAL_N

Comment: Have you tried to repair and compact database? Check this: [Solved - the size of the Access query result is larger than the maximum size of a database (2 GB)](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/ms-access-query-result-2gb.html)

Comment: Yes, didn't work.

Comment: Try to remove unnecesarry linked-tables. Compact database again and run your query. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: The thing is that I've to use the 3 table to get the output because each one is depending on another. I will try to Compact again and let you know.

Comment: Didn't work again.. still getting the error.

Comment: How large is your MySQL database, and how large is your Access one? You could use a second database to execute this query, and then insert it into the first one, using linked tables. And then you could fragment the query using the `LIMIT` keyword, since it's actually MySQL and not Access SQL

Comment: can it be done with an update using the maths you have straight into total_tbl and .execute?

Comment: I've 5 link tables from external data they are not consuming much size and 3 other tables that I've created. My access file size is 162,440 KB.

Comment: Nathan_Sav I didn't get ur point.

Comment: `insert into [total_tbl] (NEW_FIELD_NAME) VALUES (SELECT SUM(x) FROM OTHER TABLE)`  like so.   Also look at using your query like so,  `select sum(q.x) from (select MONT_VOL.tot_n*STD_tbl.factor_n as x) as q`

Comment: Silly question: you do have enough disk space (at least 2GB), right?

Comment: Yes I have more than 2 GB.

Comment: Has this anything to do with MySQL? If no, please remove the tag. If yes, which table(s) are from MySQL and which are from Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query is too big (which the error message indicates), then let's split it into smaller chunks. This is only properly possible in MySQL, Access doesn't support `LIMIT` or `OFFSET`, workarounds are messy, especially for totals queries

I'm making a few assumptions here:

1. All relevant tables are stored within the same MySQL database
2. Your tables have valid connection strings that can be used for ADO

Note that executing the query in MySQL alone is probably enough to fix this error.

```
Private Sub Get_Value()
    Dim sql As String
    Dim STD As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ODR As DAO.Recordset
    Set ODR = db.OpenRecordset("Total_tbl")
    'Create a new ADODB connection that's directly to MySQL, and doesn't use Access
    Dim adoConn2 As ADODB.Connection
    adoConn2.ConnectionString = CurrentDb.TableDefs("MONT_VOL").Connect
    adoConn2.Open
    'Initialize variables used for pagination
    Dim RecordCount As Integer
    Dim PageSize As Integer
    Dim Offset As Integer
    Offset = 0
    RecordCount = 1
    PageSize = 100
    Do Until ODR.EOF
    DoEvents

    While RecordCount <> 0
        sql = "SELECT SUM(MONT_VOL.tot_n* STD_tbl.factor_n)AS TOTAL_N FROM MONT_VOL " & _
        " INNER JOIN (STD_tbl INNER JOIN Total_tbl ON STD_tbl.AREA =Total_tbl.AREA_1" & _
        " AND STD_tbl.AID = Total_tbl.AID)" & _
        " ON MONT_VOL.BID = STD_tbl.BLOCK" & _
        " WHERE MONT_VOL.BDATE = Total_tbl.Adate" & _
        " GROUP BY MONT_VOL.BID" & _
        " LIMIT " & Offset & "," & PageSize

        STD.Open sql, adoConn2, adOpenStatic
        RecordCount = STD.RecordCount
            If STD.RecordCount <> 0 Then
                ODR.Edit
                ODR!New_Col = STD!TOTAL_N
                ODR.Update
            End If

            STD.Close
            Offset = Offset + PageSize
        Wend
        ODR.MoveNext
    Loop
    adoConn2.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Now another error came out what's the reason? **[Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.** It highlight  `adoConn2.Open`.

Comment: Well, as said, the assumption was all tables were in MySQL and all tables had valid connection strings. Where is the table `MONT_VOL` located?

Comment: it's a link table from the server.(External Data)

Comment: can you `Debug.Print TableDefs("MONT_VOL").Connect` (replace password and username with `xxxx`, if any)?

Comment: Then that table isn't linked to a table in MySQL, and you can't do passthrough queries on it. Please edit your question to properly reflect which tables are in MySQL, and which are in Access

Comment: I did some changes in my query, using oracle it gave me an output but when I use it in my program it return null value (error 94).

Comment: Please be clear about which databases you are using, and if things are linked or not. Oracle is not MySQL. If you are unclear about your setup, we won't be able to help you

Comment: Sorry I will be more clear, I've created the database in access and get some link tables from ODBC Database. The table I'm trying to store the total in is created by me(New table) in the new database. What I understand is that I've made some mistakes in the sql query and fixed it, but now it show me runtime error 94. I tried to run only the sql query using "Query Design" in ACCESS and the query worked, so I don't understand why in the module editor it tell me that I've null value?